# iPhone: Expected '{' before '(' token

Tags: iphone, objective-c, syntax

I'm currently developing an iPhone application, and when it comes to compiling, I have the aforementioned error. Here's the block of code it's on:

```
-(void)tableView(UITableView *)tableView{
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NextViewController *nextController = [[NextViewController alloc]
                                          initWithNibName::@"NextView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController
                                         animated:YES];
    [nextController changeItemTable:[arryClientSide
                                     objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

And the very first line in that block of code is where the error is. If you would like more code, please do ask.

Regards,
Jack

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First line:

```
-(void)tableView(UITableView *)tableView{
```

should be

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

Answer (score 1):

your missing a colon, as per docs:

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: Vladimir's answer is also perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView(UITableView *)tableView{
```

You need a : before parameter like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
```

// edit: without the "{" at the end

Comment: you missed the stray { on the end of that line. It doesn't need to be there, it's in the middle of a method signature.

Comment: Urg, didn't look at the second line carefully enough :>

Answer (score 0):

You should also include the line at the end of your method

```
[nextController release];
```